# I forgot my phone pattern and need to reset it or at least retrieve data from it. how can i do this?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, locked-out, android-device-manager, pattern-lock

I forgot my phone pattern. Unfortunately, in the lollipop update as there is no forgot password option, I do not seem to get any other solutions.

I am unable to change the lock password using android-device-manager because it only changes passwords and not patterns. (ring feature works though)

I am able to connect to the WiFi at home, since it is already saved.

I badly need the data on my phone. Any possible solutions?

My phone is not rooted, able to connect to already saved WiFi networks and also connected to google accounts.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't even unlock your phone, I assume? If so, I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but: if you get the password wrong enough times it will disable your phone for however long (30 seconds I think). Then on your lock screen I believe you should have an "emergency pin" option or something similar. Just enter your pin and that should unlock your phone.

Is this what you mean?
Hope it helps.
Or this might have something: 
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97840/p/30,6720,9102

Answer (score 0):

This phone I had is number pattern locked.   Luckily it is also rooted.

So the answer is easy:  Use Android SDK's adb to "cd" to /data/system directory, and remove two file: password.key and gesture.key.

Once removed, just enter "reboot" (while still inside the adb shell connected to the phone via USB) to reboot the phone, and number pattern is now unlock.